# How to draw a box (diagram?) that is have words inside a box?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

Is it easier to draw a several box and have words inside the box in latex?
I feel Latex looks nicer, rather than I draw in Words document and save as picture and insert picture to latex.

I want to have the box like below:

[image]

Comment: consider providing an MWE?

Comment: With `tikz`, boxes containing text are called `node`. See the : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52761/tikz-diagram-with-stacks-and-box

Comment: @AndréC. Thanks. I am quite new to Latex, and not sure where I can start from. I able to understand very simple code like `\begin{tikzpicture}[stack/.style={
  rectangle split, rectangle split parts=5,` but not sure how to make a large rectangular box.

Comment: It is simple to obtain with `tabularx`, `hhline` and `colortbl`. You  don't need a hammersledge to crack a nut.

Comment: For starters, forget about `style` and write simple `node`. Once you understand the basic mechanism, you can start to see what styles are.

Comment: @AndréC. Thanks. Can you give a very simple example?

Answer (score 10):

As `tikz` image, used `fit` and `matrix` libraries and the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,
                matrix}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,     
                  leftmargin = *         ,
                  before     = \vspace{-0.4\baselineskip},
                     }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
F/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{draw, fill=#1, 
                           label={[text width=120mm,
                                   text=#2,
                                   align=center]center:#3},
                           inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
                           node contents={}
                          },
        font = \sffamily
                        ]
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             nodes in empty cells,
             nodes={thin, draw,
                    minimum height=4ex, text width=30mm, 
                    inner sep=1mm, outer sep=0pt, anchor=north},
             column sep=2mm,
                row sep=2mm,
                row 3/.style = {nodes={fill=black, text=white}},
                row 4/.style = {nodes={minimum height=5.4\baselineskip}},
                row 5/.style = {row sep=\pgflinewidth,
                                nodes={fill=black, text=white}},
             ]
{   
    &       &       &       \\
    &       &       &       \\
Primary Objectives  
    & Experimental design   
            & Fixed Section/Part    
                    & Testing Variables   \\    
    \begin{itemize}
\item   first item
\item   second item
\item   third item has at least two lines
    \end{itemize}\vfill
    &    \begin{itemize}
    \item   first item
    \item   second item
    \item   third item has at least two lines
    \item   forth item
        \end{itemize}
        &    \begin{itemize}
        \item   first item
        \item   second item
        \item   third item has at least two lines
        \item   forth item
            \end{itemize}
            &    \begin{itemize}
            \item   first item
            \item   second item
            \item   third item has at least two lines
            \item   forth item
                \end{itemize}   \\
    &       &       &           \\
    &       &       &           \\[4mm]
    &       &       &           \\
    &       &       &          \\
};
\node[F=gray!30/black/Study 1,
      fit=(m-1-1) (m-1-4)];
\node[F=white/black/{Aim: Investigate the peformance /
                          and some more text},
      fit=(m-2-1) (m-2-4)];
\node[F=black/white/Hyaphotesis,
      fit=(m-5-1) (m-5-4)];
\node[F=white/black/\begin{itemize}
                \item   H1: Investigate the peformance
                \item   H2: Investigate the peformance
                    \end{itemize},
    minimum height=2\baselineskip,
    fit=(m-6-1) (m-6-4)];
\node[F=gray!30/black/Study 2,
      fit=(m-7-1) (m-7-4)];
\node[F=white/black/{Aim: Investigate the peformance /
                          and some more text},
      fit=(m-8-1) (m-8-4)];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: in the case when you like to add more "fit" nodes to your diagram, for example node

```
 \node[F=gray!30/black/Study 3, fit=(m-9-1) (m-9-4)];
```

you need first extend matrix with one more row with empty cells.

Comment: thanks. Just one question, if I want to add in `Study 3`, I had tried `\node[F=gray!30/black/Study 3, fit=(m-9-1) (m-9-4)];`, but seemed not working. Did I miss out something?

Comment: @aan, do you first write ninth row (of empty cells) in matrix?

Comment: I just tried `row 7/.style = {nodes={fill=black, text=white}},`, not sure is this called empty cells? I tried `row 9/.style = {nodes={fill=black, text=white}},`

Comment: @ann, no, this just format row 7. You new write additional row in the matrix. See edited answer.

Comment: thanks. I am trying it again. Sorry, which part is to add `additional row in the matrix`?

Comment: I tried and test. I think I got it `&&&\\` is for `additional row`

Comment: Very very very nice. I appreciated lot also your work.

Comment: @Zarko, yes, brillant. You really good. Can I ask one question? If i want to make the  vertically box large, i put `&&&\\ [5mm]`. How about making the horizontally box larger?

Comment: @ann,  `& & &\\[5mm]` insert row of empty cell and additional vertical space of `5mm` after it (as it is after 6th row in MWE). Is this what you like to have? In the case that some cell is higher, for example as is cell in the 6th row, than you need to change `minimum height` of those cells. For example, for the forth row in MWE it is defined with : `row 4/.style = {nodes={minimum height=5.4\baselineskip}},`

Answer (score 6):

The following based on `tabularx` might serve as a starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{3}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|c|}X|}
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{\cellcolor{gray}Study 1}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{c}{}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{Aim: some text here}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{c}{}\\
\hhline{-~-~-~-}
\cellcolor{black}\textcolor{white}{Primary Objectives} && \cellcolor{black}\textcolor{white}{Experimental Design} && \cellcolor{black}\textcolor{white} {Fixed Section/ Part} && \cellcolor{black}\textcolor{white} {Testing Variables}\\
\hhline{-~-~-~-}
\multicolumn{7}{c}{}\\
\hhline{-~-~-~-}
 some text here &&  some other text here &&  more in this cell &&  additional text here\\
 \hhline{-~-~-~-}
 \multicolumn{7}{c}{}\\
 \hline
\multicolumn{7}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{\cellcolor{black}\textcolor{white}{Hypothesis}}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. Didnt know can draw using a table. I have one question for `\usepackage{calc}`, it said `Latex Error: Option clash with package xcolour`.

Comment: @aan: The `calc` package will most likely not be the cause for the quoted error message. Did you load the `xcolor` package twice and with different options?

Answer (score 4):

With TikZ, a box that contains text is called a `node`. To start, let's forget about `style`, once you understand the basic syntax, you can use them.

#### 1. Here is a simple example without any style.

I use the `positioning` library which allows to place the `node` in relation to each other. 
I proceeded by trial and error to find the width of the top one.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,fill=black,text=white] (primary) at (0,0) {Primary objectives};
\node[draw,fill=black,text=white](experimental)[right=of primary]  {Experimental Design};
\node[draw,fill=black,text=white](section)[right=of experimental]  {Fixed section / Part};
\node[draw,fill=black,text=white](testing)[right=of section]  {Testing variables};
\node[draw](aim)[above=of primary.west,anchor=west,minimum width=15.8cm]{Aim: investigate the performance / Investigate  Investigate Investigate Investigate};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

#### 2. More precise relative placements:

It is possible to fix a `minimum width` to the box. This is appropriate here because the text is smaller than the box. 
I fixed it at `3.5cm`. The distance between the nodes can be set **globally** with the key `node distance=2mm`.

Likewise, by setting a `minimum height` greater than each text, here `minimum height=2em` the boxes all have the same height.
At each node, TikZ adds an invisible outer margin which by default measures half of the line width, here `0.4 pt`. By setting this value to `outer sep=0pt`, the top box is as wide as the four boxes below it.

So the width of the top box is `4x3.5cm + 3x0.2cm=14.6cm.`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2mm,minimum width=3.5cm,minimum height=2em,outer sep=0pt]
```

This key `node distance=2mm` only works if the distance between two nodes is **not** set locally. 
For example, I placed the top node `1mm` above the other nodes. And so the global key `node distance=2mm` is not active.

I position this box above its `north west` corner and not above its `west` edge to avoid overlapping boxes.

`\node[draw](aim)[above=1mm of primary.north west,anchor=south west,minimum width=14.6cm]{Aim: investigate the performance / Investigate Investigate Investigate Investigate Investigate};` and so the `node distance=2mm` option is ignored.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2mm,minimum width=3.5cm,minimum height=2em,outer sep=0pt]
\node[draw,fill=black,text=white] (primary) at (0,0) {Primary objectives};
\node[draw,fill=black,text=white](experimental)[right=of primary]  {Experimental Design};
\node[draw,fill=black,text=white](section)[right=of experimental]  {Fixed section / Part};
\node[draw,fill=black,text=white](testing)[right=of section]  {Testing variables};
\node[draw](aim)[above=1mm of primary.north west,anchor=south west,minimum width=14.6cm]{Aim: investigate the performance / Investigate  Investigate Investigate Investigate};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. I can easily understand your code. Thanks. Between, how to make the box larger in size? I want to have box 1 and box 2 close and large enough.

Comment: @aan That's it, I've added some details about the relative placement of the nodes.

Comment: @aan I just added complements on the outer margin `outer sep=0pt` and the minimum height of each box `minimum height=2em`.

Answer (score 4):

I think that leandriis answer is the way to go, but *if* you want to use Ti*k*Z, use a matrix. You can then use the aux file to synchronize the relevant dimensions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,positioning}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\WriteAux}[1]{%
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string#1{#1}\relax}}
\makeatother
\pgfkeys{initialize dimension/.code={\unless\ifdefined#1
 \def#1{0pt}
 \fi}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,node distance=1ex]
  \pgfkeys{initialize dimension/.list={\myheightA,\myheightB,\mywidth}}
  \node[draw,text width=\mywidth,align=center,fill=gray](Study){Study 1};
  \node[below=of Study,draw,text width=\mywidth,align=center](aim){Aim: Investigate the
  performance\,/\,Investigate Investigate Investigate Investigate};
  \node[below=of aim,matrix of nodes,nodes={text width=0.2\textwidth,align=left,
      fill,text=white,minimum height=\myheightA,inner sep=2pt,anchor=north},
    column sep=1ex,inner sep=0pt] (matA) {
    {Primary Objectives} &
    {Experimental design} &
    {Fixed Section/Part} &
    {Primary Objectives} \\
  };
  \node[below=of matA,matrix of nodes,nodes={text width=0.2\textwidth,align=left,
      draw,minimum height=\myheightB,inner sep=2pt,anchor=north},
    column sep=1ex,inner sep=0pt] (matB) {
  {\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\begin{itemize}
  \item bla
  \item blub
  \end{itemize}} &
  {\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\begin{itemize}
  \item bla
  \item blub
  \end{itemize}} &
  {\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\begin{itemize}
  \item bla
  \item blub
  \item pft
  \end{itemize}} &
  {\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\begin{itemize}
  \item bla
  \item blub
  \end{itemize}} \\
  };
  \node[below=of matB,text width=\mywidth,fill,text=white,draw,align=center] (Hypo)
   {Hypotheses};
  \node[below=0pt of Hypo,text width=\mywidth,align=left,draw] (Pft)
   {\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\begin{itemize}
  \item bla
  \item blub
  \end{itemize}};
  \node[below=1.5em of Pft,draw,text width=\mywidth,align=center,fill=gray](Study2){Study 2};
  \node[below=of Study2,draw,text width=\mywidth,align=center](aim2){Aim: Investigate the
  performance\,/\,Investigate Investigate Investigate Investigate};
  % book keeping:
  \path let \p1=($(matB-1-1.north)-(matB-1-1.south)$),
      \p2=($(matB-1-2.north)-(matB-1-2.south)$),
      \p3=($(matB-1-3.north)-(matB-1-3.south)$),
      \p4=($(matB-1-4.north)-(matB-1-4.south)$),
      \n1={max(\y1,\y2,\y3,\y4)},
      \p5=($(matB.east)-(matB.west)$),
      \p6=($(matA-1-1.north)-(matA-1-1.south)$),
      \p7=($(matA-1-2.north)-(matA-1-2.south)$),
      \p8=($(matA-1-3.north)-(matA-1-3.south)$),
      \p9=($(matA-1-4.north)-(matA-1-4.south)$),
      \n2={max(\y6,\y7,\y8,\y9)}     in
  \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{\x5-8pt}\edef\mywidth{\mywidth pt}\edef\myheightA{\n2}\edef\myheightB{\n1}%
      \WriteAux{\mywidth}\WriteAux{\myheightA}\WriteAux{\myheightB}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{Some table.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I should have maybe stressed that in this answer you everything will adjust if you decide to make, say, some node above the matrix taller....

Answer (score 3):

For such clear structures, I think it's easier to use a `tcbraster` or `tcbitemize` from `tcolorbox`. Here you have a starting point example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
    sharp corners,
    fontupper=\sffamily,
    halign=center,
    study/.style={colback=black!30},
    aim/.style={colback=white},
    text/.style={colback=white, halign=left},
    name/.style={colback=black, colupper=white}
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=4]
\tcbitem[study, raster multicolumn=4] Study 1
\tcbitem[aim, raster multicolumn=4] Aim: Investigate the performance/Investigate Investigate
\tcbitem[name] Primary Objectyives
\tcbitem[name] Experimental Design
\tcbitem[name] Fixed Section/Part
\tcbitem[name] Testing Variables
\tcbitem[text, halign=left] - Investigate\\ - System Investigate\\ - Investigate
\tcbitem[text] - Investigate\\ - System Investigate\\ - Investigate
\tcbitem[text] - Investigate\\ - System Investigate\\ - Investigate
\tcbitem[text] - Investigate\\ - System Investigate\\ - Investigate
\tcbitem[name, raster multicolumn=4] Hypotheses
\tcbitem[text, raster multicolumn=4] \begin{itemize}
\item H1: Investigate the performance/Investigate
\item H2: Investigate the performance/Investigate
\end{itemize}
\tcbitem[study, raster multicolumn=4] Study 2
\tcbitem[aim, raster multicolumn=4] Aim: Investigate the performance/Investigate Investigate
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I vote up also your nice answer.

Comment: @lgnasi, thanks. Is `tcbset` conflict with `\usepackage{hhline, boldline}`? Can I have both in overleaf? It seemed cannot