# How do I draw cells around numbers/letters?

Tags: tables

Given this:

0 1 2 3

t e s t

How can I draw cells around numbers and letters as well? Of course they also have to be centered.

I tried the table command but I got stuck

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Buffer }  
\centering     
\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
```

Comment: Please post a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that can be compiled. Your MWE doesn't contain enough information anyway. E.g. what do you mean by 'cells around numbers and letters'? Each number/letter should be contained in a cell? Are there any spacing requirements? What shape should the cell assume (I guess square)? etc.

Comment: *Maybe*, aside from an MWE, adding a picture of what you are trying to achieve will help.

Comment: Like Excel cells ...just simple square..Both lines should be aligned

Comment: Guessing a little from your caption, the following might also be of use: [How to draw  stack diagram with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26370/2693).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*For update, scroll down.*

Without MWE or picture, I am totally free to flood out my imaginations `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
t & e & s & t\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Update:

To make the cells of same width, one can define a new column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.3cm}}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*4{M|}}\hline
0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|*4{M|}}\hline
t & e & s & t\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted..test's cells seem to be smaller ..How can I make them as large as the other ones?

Comment: @g9999: You can include both in the same `tabular`.

Answer (score 11):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\begin{document}
\begin{TAB}(e){|c|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|}% horizontan/vertical
0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
t & e & s & t\\
T & e & s & t
\end{TAB}

\begin{TAB}(e,1cm,1cm,1cm,1cm){|c|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
t & e & s & t\\
T & e & s & t
\end{TAB}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice & minimal `:)`

Answer (score 5):

Here's a more general take on the problem:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x/\cellcontent in {0/t,1/e,2/s,3/t}   
        \node[draw,shape=rectangle] at (\x,0) {\strut\cellcontent};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Like this you can space your cells as far apart as you like and the heights of the boxes will be all equal. Also you could customize your cells: shape, color, etc.

Obvously, it needs you to load `TikZ`.

**EDIT**: I extended the above example to show how you could do the cells with a single counter if they contain consecutive numbers:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x/\cellcontent in {0/t,1/e,2/s,3/t}   
        \node[draw,shape=rectangle] at (\x,0) {\strut\cellcontent};
    \foreach \x in {1,...,4}    
        \node[draw,shape=rectangle] at ($(\x-1,2)$) {\strut \x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This will additionally require the `calc` library of `TikZ`.

[image]

Comment: Amazing...I'll try it out...immediately