# Easiest way of drawing a graph in LaTeX

Tags: diagrams

So, I'm looking for the easiest way of drawing something like this. It's a simple diagram.

[image]

Is [the picture environment](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Picture) the most appropiate one?

Comment: related : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26370/how-to-draw-stack-diagram-with-tikz

Comment: I would use the tikzpicture environment to create it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and multipart rectangles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,shapes.arrows}

\tikzset{
mystack/.style={
  draw,
  rectangle split,
  rectangle split parts=#1,
  text width=2cm,
  align=center,
  anchor=north east,
  font=\ttfamily}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% The stack to the left
\node[mystack=2] at (0,0) (sta1)   
  {stack\nodepart{two}\rule{0pt}{2cm}};
\draw[white,line width=3pt] (sta1.south west) -- (sta1.south east);
\node[fill=red!50,single arrow,rotate=-90,text width=10pt] at (sta1) {};

% The stack to the right
\node[mystack=3] at (5,0) (sta2) 
  {0$\times$AAA\nodepart{two}0$\times\cdots$\nodepart{three}\rule{0pt}{1.5cm}};
\draw[white,line width=3pt] (sta2.south west) -- (sta2.south east);

% The red and black arrows
\draw[line width=2pt,red,->] 
  ([xshift=1cm]sta1.east) -- ++(20pt,0);
\draw[line width=1pt,<-] 
  ([xshift=5pt]sta2.two split east) -- ++(10pt,0) node[right] {ESP};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for `\draw[white ...` at lower border and `\rule{0pt}...` to fix stack height. Could you explain how do you know each stack line height is 5mm?

Comment: @Ignasi thanks for the vote! Regarding your question, I'm a little confused; which are the stack lines you are referring to?

Comment: In `sta1` you use `\rule{0pt}{2cm}` while in `\sta2` rule heigth is only 1.5cm, and both stacks show same height. How did you decide this 5mm difference?

Comment: @Ignasi ah, now I understand. Well, the values were just found "by eye" (I'm not sure if that's the right English expression).

Answer (score 1):

I think that a good choice is the `pstricks` package, or any other design/draw software.

Use `graphics` package to include `.jpg`, `.eps`, `.png`... files in the `.tex` file.

Here you can see some examples:

http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/

http://www.tn-home.de/Tobias/Soft/TeX/TUG040611/presentation.pdf

If you want to write me, you can do it in spanish at `NOTHINGmika2ikeNOTHING@gmail.com`. I'm starting learning PSTricks. If you are using it, remember to compile with xelatex or use other options like the ones you can find here:

[How to use PSTricks in pdfLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8413/how-to-use-pstricks-in-pdflatex)