# Drawing stacks side-by-side in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, stack

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26373/88590) question, Alan Munn provided an example of how to draw a stack in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[stack/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=#1,draw, anchor=center}]
\node[stack=5]  {
\nodepart{two}a
\nodepart{three}b
\nodepart{four}c
\nodepart{five}d
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

However, I would like to display 4 stacks side-by-side.  How can this be done?

Comment: should be some distance between your "staks"? are all stack have the same number and size of cells? or this stacks form a matrix?

Comment: It dosn't matter how much distance is between the stacks. The stacks will have different amounts of cells but should all be aligned the the bottom. Cells may have different sizes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To place additional stacks just portion the new nodes appropriately:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    stack/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=#1,draw, anchor=center}
]

\node[stack=5] (A) {
    \nodepart{two}a
    \nodepart{three}b
    \nodepart{four}c
    \nodepart{five}d
};
\node[stack=5, right of=A] (B) {
    \nodepart{two}a
    \nodepart{three}b
    \nodepart{four}c
    \nodepart{five}d
};
\node[stack=5, right of=B] (C) {
    \nodepart{two}a
    \nodepart{three}b
    \nodepart{four}c
    \nodepart{five}d
};
\node[stack=5, right of=C] (D) {
    \nodepart{two}a
    \nodepart{three}b
    \nodepart{four}c
    \nodepart{five}d
};

\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

with library `matrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             nodes={draw, minimum width=1.5em, minimum height=2ex, outer sep=0pt},
             row sep    = -\pgflinewidth,
             column sep = -\pgflinewidth % <--- as matrix
             ]
{   a   &   a   &   a   &   a   \\
    b   &   b   &   b   &   b   \\
    c   &   c   &   c   &   c   \\
    d   &   d   &   d   &   d   \\
};
\matrix (n) [right=of m,
             matrix of nodes,
             nodes={draw, minimum width=1.5em, minimum height=2ex, outer sep=0pt},
             row sep    = -\pgflinewidth,
             column sep = 2em  % <--- as separate stacks
             ]
{   a   &   a   &   a   &   a   \\
    b   &   b   &   b   &   b   \\
    c   &   c   &   c   &   c   \\
    d   &   d   &   d   &   d   \\
};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Really just 4 fun (and to answer a Ti*k*Z question with a non-Ti*k*Z answer, usually I am doing the opposite ;-).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{youngtab}
\begin{document}
\young(~,a,b,c,~)\quad\young(~,a,b,c,~)\quad\young(~,a,b,c,~)\quad\young(~,a,b,c,~)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here I use `stackengine` instead of `tikz`.  I create the macro `\wstack` with a comma separated list to stack.  The term `\wboxstrut` defines the minimum vertical footprint of the stacked items, initially set to the footprint of `w` and later changed to `\strut`, which will have the effect of aligning all box edges.

Automatically adjusts to content width.

It uses `\fboxrule` and `\fboxsep` to define the box rule and offset.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,listofitems}
\def\wboxwidth{.7em}
\def\wboxstrut{\vphantom{w}}
\newcommand\wbox[1]{\fbox{\makebox[\wboxwidth]{#1\wboxstrut}}}
\newcommand\wstack[1]{%
  \setsepchar{,}%
  \setstackEOL{,}%
  \savestack\tmp{\Shortstack{#1}}%
  \def\wboxwidth{\wd\tmpcontent}%
  \readlist\boxitems{#1}%
  \savestack\boxbuild{\wbox{\boxitems[-1]}}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\boxitems{%
    \ifnum\xcnt=1\relax\else%
      \savestack\boxbuild{\stackon[-\fboxrule]{\boxbuild}{\wbox{\boxitems[-\xcnt]}}}%
    \fi%
  }%
  \boxbuild%
}
\begin{document}
\wstack{,a,b,c,d}
\wstack{,a,b,c}
\wstack{b,c,d}
\wstack{,aaa,b,c,d}\qquad
\def\wboxstrut{\strut}
\wstack{,a,b,c,d}
\wstack{,a,b,c}
\wstack{b,c,d}
\wstack{,aaa,b,c,d}
\end{document}
```

[image]